# connect my noSQL(mongoDB) database with my nodeJS project. But it is not working fine

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to connect my nodejs with mongoDB but it is not working fine as the following result below.
**

```
(node:11776) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your o
wn promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

{ MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0
.1:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (D:\KIT\YEAR II\Project\Nodejs\Vidjot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:336:3
5)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (D:\KIT\YEAR II\Project\Nodejs\Vidjot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:2
80:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\KIT\YEAR II\Project\Nodejs\Vidjot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js
:187:49)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1
:27017]' }
```

**
[Here is my source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUGcl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your mongo server is running @ localhost:27017 and you have directories created to store data.
 start using this command:

```
>mongod --port 27017 --dbpath c:\data\db
```

Comment: It showed me the following command error after i executed it : 
bash: mongod: command not found

Comment: Have you installed mongodb? If yes check out how to set mongodb path as environment variable or go to c:\Program File\mongo\server\bin and then execute the command

Comment: Here is the result after i executed 'mongod --port 27017'

`2017-12-07T09:56:24.606-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=13972 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=zlatan
2017-12-07T09:56:24.606-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2017-12-07T09:56:24.607-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.9
2017-12-07T09:56:24.607-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 876ebee8c7dd0e2d992f36a848ff4dc50ee6603e
2017-12-07T09:56:24.607-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1u-fips  22 Sep 2016`

Comment: `2017-12-07T09:56:24.607-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1u-fips  22 Sep 2016
2017-12-07T09:56:24.608-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-12-07T09:56:24.608-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-12-07T09:56:24.609-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-12-07T09:56:24.609-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
2017-12-07T09:56:24.610-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-12-07T09:56:24.611-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64`

Comment: Is it waiting for connection?

Comment: It is not sir! I don't know the main problem